# Is it possible to process math calculation before stringify a macro?

Tags: c, macros, stringification

I look through a lot of examples online about macro stringification but can't find something similar.

I currently have the definitions as below.

```
#define PIN_A (0+1)
#define PIN_B (0+2)
#define PIN_C (0+3)
#define str(x) #x
#define xstr(x) str(x)
#define PIN_DEF(x) { #x, xstr(PIN_ ## x) }
```

The output of

```
PIN_DEF(A)
```

will become

```
{ "A", "(0+1)" }
```

However, what I really need is

```
{ "A", "1" }
```

Is it even possible? :/

Comment: No, I don’t think that’s possible.  The preprocessor only does text substitution and the arithmetic is not text substitution. It does arithmetic only in conditional expressions.

Comment: No and this kind of macros should avoided as a plaque

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db6d9dde19800543), it's possible.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic.hpp>
#define PIN_A BOOST_PP_ADD(0,1)
#define PIN_B BOOST_PP_ADD(0,2)
#define PIN_C BOOST_PP_ADD(0,3)
#define str(x) #x
#define xstr(x) str(x)
#define PIN_DEF(x) { #x, xstr(PIN_##x) }

PIN_DEF(A)
```

Keep in mind boost preprocessor's arithmetic macros saturate at `256`.

### Caveats

The *preprocessor* can also evaluate expressions, but the only means of doing so is to invoke preprocessor conditional directives (such as `#if` *<expression>*/`#elif` *<expression>*).  You can make a useful expression evaluator out of this, with usage limitations, but it doesn't seem to fit this use case.  *Macro* math needs to be adopted to macro usage (and essentially implemented from scratch), so operations must be implemented in terms of macro calls.